# SQL Server 2012 - A Little Guidance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have searched the net but I am certain I must not be phrasing my keywords correctly because I am not finding possible solutions for my problem.   think it might be recursion but I'm not quite certain.

I have a table that has the following categories:

```
ID, Author, Customer, Group
```

A sample dataset would be like:

```
  ID |      Author    | Customer  | Group
------------------------------------------ 
   1 |  Paula Hawkins | John Doe  | NULL
   2 |  Harlan Coben  | John Doe  | NULL
   3 | James Patterson| John Doe  | NULL    
   4 |  Paula Hawkins | Jane Doe  | NULL    
   5 | James Patterson| Jane Doe  | NULL
   6 | James Patterson| Steven Doe| NULL    
   7 |  Harlan Coben  | Steven Doe| NULL
   8 |  Paula Hawkins | Harry Doe | NULL    
   9 | James Patterson| Harry Doe | NULL
```

Its possible a customer may have one ore more then one author checked out so what I am trying to do is group them with a unique id based on what total are checked out (regardless of the customer name):

```
 ID  |      Author    |  Customer  | Group
--------------------------------------------   
  1  |  Paula Hawkins |  John Doe  |   1    
  2  |  Harlan Coben  |  John Doe  |   1
  3  | James Patterson|  John Doe  |   1
  4  |  Paula Hawkins |  Jane Doe  |   2    
  5  | James Patterson|  Jane Doe  |   2    
  6  | James Patterson| Steven Doe |   3    
  7  |  Harlan Coben  | Steven Doe |   3    
  8  |  Paula Hawkins |  Harry Doe |   2    
  9  | James Patterson|  Harry Doe |   2
```

its very possible the same customer could be found hundreds of times for multiple books so the final group category would represent the unique value for that customer (other customers would have the same value only if everything they have checked out also matches everything the other customer has checked out).

Using the above data, Harry and Jane have the exact same authors checked out so they are in the same group but John and Steven have different combinations so they have their own unique group.

Hopefully this makes sense.  Is this what is called recursion?  If so then I will look towards a cte solution that uses some sort of ranking for the unique id value.  Thanks for any help you give.

Comment: Can you add what you want to see as a result, data-wise, based on your sample data? It's still a bit unclear what you actually want to see there, at least for me. (pardon my incompetence)

Comment: The top group with the NULL is the before and the bottom group with a value would be the after.  Basically a value would be set that would identify each unique group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to get your exact group order, but to just group customers together you can combine their authors with FOR XML and group the customers based on exact matches.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  
        *,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Authors) [Group]
    FROM (  
        SELECT 
            [Customer],
            STUFF((SELECT ',' + [Author]
                   FROM myTable WHERE Customer = mt.Customer
                   ORDER BY Author
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Authors
        FROM
            myTable mt
        GROUP BY [Customer] ) t
)

SELECT  
    mt.[ID],
    mt.[Author],
    mt.[Customer],
    cte.[Group]
FROM 
    cte 
    JOIN myTable mt ON mt.Customer = cte.Customer
ORDER BY mt.[ID]
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/427b2/1)

Comment: I'll play around with this as I have never tried an XML solution but based on the initial results it created over 136 groups id's but I was expecting something along the line of around 40 at most so I may be missing a group flag in my query.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back with you but this math professor is killing me.  I was able to get this to work for my problem now I just need to read up on xml to understand why.  Thanks for the direction, it certainly has gotten me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cursors...  Cursors are slow, but they're also easier to understand..

Here's a sample implementation...

```
DECLARE @GroupExists Bit
DECLARE @CurrGroup Int
DECLARE @NextGroup Int
DECLARE @Customer VARCHAR(250)

SET @NextGroup = 1

DECLARE customer_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT distinct Customer FROM dbo.TableName

OPEN customer_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM customer_cursor
INTO @Customer

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    SET @GroupExists = 0
    --Test condition to check if group of authors in in use

    IF @GroupExists = 1 Then
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.TableName
        SET Group = @CurrGroup
        WHERE Customer = @Customer
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.TableName
        SET Group = @NextGroup
        WHERE Customer = @Customer

        SET @NextGroup= @NextGroup+ 1
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM customer_cursor   
    INTO @Customer
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate groups using standard SQL. The following query should do the job; I make no promises of its performance though.

```
WITH
CTE_CheckOutBookCount AS
(
    SELECT   [ID]
            ,[Author]   
            ,[Customer]
            ,COUNT([Author]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Customer]) AS [CheckOutBooks] -- Count the number of books checked out by each customer. This will be used for our initial compare between customers.
    FROM    CheckedOutBooks
),
CTE_AuthorAndCountCompare AS
(
    SELECT           CB.[ID]
                    ,CBC.[Customer] AS MatchedCustomers 
    FROM            CTE_CheckOutBookCount CB
    INNER JOIN  CTE_CheckOutBookCount CBC ON CB.[Author] = CBC.[Author] AND CB.[CheckOutBooks] = CBC.[CheckOutBooks] --Join customer information on number of books checked out and author name of books checked out.
)
,CTE_MatchedCustomers
AS
(
    SELECT  
             [ID]
            ,[Author]   
            ,[Customer]
            --Get the minimum record id of customers which match exactly on count and authors checked out. This will be used to help generate group ID.
            ,(
                SELECT  MIN(ID)
                FROM    CTE_AuthorAndCountCompare
                WHERE   CheckedOutBooks.[Customer] = CTE_AuthorAndCountCompare.MatchedCustomers
            ) MinID
    FROM    CheckedOutBooks
)
SELECT  
         [ID]
        ,[Author]   
        ,[Customer]
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MinID) AS [Group] -- Generate new group id
FROM    CTE_MatchedCustomers
ORDER BY ID
```